# Is there a way to detect if the charger is disconnected

Tags: macos, event-handling

Is there a way to detect if the charger is disconnected on a **mac** computer.

i.e. is it possible to make an app that listens for an "charger-connected"/"charger-disconnected" event?

Like For ios:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setBatteryMonitoringEnabled:YES];

if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] batteryState] == UIDeviceBatteryStateCharging) {
    NSLog(@"Device is charging.");
}
```

But I would like an event-listener, for example: `-(void) didDisconnectCharger:(id)sender.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the function you are looking for is [IOPSNotificationCreateRunLoopSource](https://developer.apple.com/librarY/mac/documentation/IOKit/Reference/IOPowerSources_header_reference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/IOPSNotificationCreateRunLoopSource) in `IOKit`.